# Is there a way to make 32-bit Mozilla Seamonkey work in a 64-bit XUbuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit, mozilla, seamonkey

My previous computer ran a 32-bit XUbuntu version 14.04 and 32-bit Mozilla Seamonkey as my default web browser. Now my new computer runs a 64-bit Xubuntu version 14.04, but there's no **official** 64-bit Mozilla Seamonkey build available. I installed the official 32-bit Mozilla Seamonkey on my 64-bit system, but the browser isn't working. When I use the command below in order to try to run its binary executable:

```
/opt/mozilla/seamonkey/seamonkey
```

...the program gives me the following reply, before exiting:

```
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I noticed that my system does have this file here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2
```

...but it's the 64-bit version (most possible reason why the 32-bit Seamonkey is rejecting this library file).

Is there any way to work this around and thus make the 32-bit Seamonkey work in my 64-bit system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to troubleshoot the problem myself and finally found a workaround.

The first thing you have to do is to activate support for the installation of 32-bit applications in your 64-bit system. You do this by running this shell command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

After that, all you have to do is to update the APT database:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

...and then run the command below in order to install the 32-bit libraries required by Mozilla SeaMonkey:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1.2:i386 libxt6:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0.0:i386 libasound2:i386 -y --reinstall
```

APT will then solve some dependencies and install them along with the libraries installed by the command above.

I did it in 64-bit XUbuntu versions 14.04 and 16.04 and it worked like a charm: now I can run the official 32-bit build of Mozilla SeaMonkey on my 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit version can be downloaded on [the main Seamonkey download page](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/releases/#contrib) under 'Contributed builds'.

Comment: I know, I had already accessed that page. But those are unofficial builds. I want to use the official build, which unfortunately is only available in 32-bit (currently). Anyway, adding support to 32-bit installation packages and then installing those 32-bit dependencies does the trick. Hope to see the SeaMonkey team eventually come up with an official 64-bit build, though. That would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested, I have a repo with installation scripts for (64-bit) Seamonkey and Firefox here:

https://github.com/sid-the-sloth/install-scripts

Please check it out and enjoy!